# copy to with a specified range

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy one sheets specific range of cell to another workbook with formatting and formulas intact.  Not sure why i cant find a solution on the forms but I am still having trouble.  This is what I'm currently using:

```
function copytosnapshot() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
var destination = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("destination_sheet");
sheet.copyTo(destination);
}
```

I also found this, but it doesnt keep formatting:

```
function Copy() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Source-ID'); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('LIVE BOARD'); //replace with source Sheet tab 
name
var range = ss.getRange('A1:AC88'); //assign the range you want to copy
var data = range.getValues();
var tss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination_ID'); 
//replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet11'); //replace with destination Sheet tab 
name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,88,29).setValues(data); //you will need to 
define the size of the copied data see getRange(). Range is 88 rows to 
column AC.
}
```

I'm guessing the first set of code can work I just need to define the variables.   This will be a set range and I don't need to pull last row or anything like that.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: The top code copies the entire sheet.  I only want a specific range of rows.

Comment: Yes, I looked at those.  Copyto wont work with ranges on different spreadsheets and the other methods i've seen dont copy formatting, but just values.  You don't have to give me the answer but a push in the right direction would be nicer than "Figure it out"

Comment: Wow, guy comments and deletes his post.  Helpful.  Anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Comment: There's no generic `setFormats(formats[][])` and `getFormats()` methods. One trick might be to copy the `Sheet` to the destination spreadsheet, then use the `Range#copyTo` method of your choice, and then delete the copied sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in two steps:

1) Use copyTo to copy values

2) Use copyFormatToRange to copy format

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangegridid-column-columnend-row-rowend